# c# mysql data adding mariadb server version for the right syntax use near

Tags: c#, mariadb

When I want to enter c # you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax use near '*) from tabloadı where tabloalanı ve eklemek istediğim bilgiler

```
private void btnkaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (baglanti.State == ConnectionState.Closed) baglanti.Open();
        string varmı = "Select Count (*) From kullanici where Kullanici_Adi=@ad";
        MySqlCommand kmtvarmı = new MySqlCommand(varmı, baglanti);
        kmtvarmı.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", txtad.Text);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(kmtvarmı.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Girdiğiniz Kullanıcı Adında Kayıt Vardır Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz!!!");
        }
        else if (txtad.Text == "" || txtsifre.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lütfen Gerekli alanları Doldurunuz!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            string kaydet = "INSERT INTO kullanici (Kullanici_Adi,Sifre,Yetki) VALUES(?ad,?sifre)";
            MySqlCommand kmtkaydet = new MySqlCommand(kaydet, baglanti);
            kmtkaydet.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ad", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "txtad.Text";
            kmtkaydet.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sifre", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "txtsifre.Text";
            kmtkaydet.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Kayıt Başarılı");
            baglanti.Close();
            verigetir();
            txtad.Text = "";
            txtsifre.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception hata)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HATA OLUŞTU  " + hata.Message);
        baglanti.Close();
    }
```

Comment: try removing the space between `COUNT` and `(`